# R time series, complicated sequence

Tags: r, merge, zoo, seq

I am attempting to merge two different time-series in R with the following characteristics:

1. Data must be between 08:30 and 15:00 on a daily basis.
2. Data spans several weeks, not just one particular day.
3. There are gaps in the data at random intervals.
4. The two datasets will not have gaps at the same intervals necessarily

I would like to merge the two datasets, with all times in the sequence from 08:30 to 15:00 and where there was a gap in each, I would like the previous value (or following value) carried over.

```
# I have verified that the csv files are imported correctly
# The first column contains dates. and the strptime
# function can convert strings into Date/Time objects.
#
sec1_dates <- strptime(sec1[,1], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
sec2_dates <- strptime(sec2[,1], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

# The second column contains the close.
# I use the zoo function to create zoo objects from that data.
# But for some reason this ends up creating duplicates PROBLEM 1
#
a <- zoo(sec1[,2], sec1_dates)
b <- zoo(sec2[,2], sec2_dates)

# I know that I need use seq to fill in gaps but I am clueless as to how
# Once I have the proper seq I can just use na.locf to fill the appropriate values
# HOWEVER seq(start(sec1_dates), end(sec1_dates), "min") would end up returning
# every minute for each day, and I only want 08:30 to 15:30. PROBLEM 2

# The merge function can combine two zoo objects, in union
# Obviously this fails because the two index sizes don't match PROBLEM 3
#
t.zoo <- merge(a, b, all=TRUE)
```

> **James you were right about Problem 1. Thank you. I verified that the csv file was pulling the data in twice and removing the data fixed the issue. I used your solution for Problem 2 as well, but I am not certain that this is the most efficient way of going about doing what I'm trying to do. Ultimately I may want to use this to run regressions, and at that point might need a loop of some sort to pull any number of datasets. Any optimizations that I might make would be greatly appreciated.**

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

```
library(zoo)
library(tseries)

# Read the CSV files into data frames
sec1 <- read.csv("C:\\exportdata\\sec1.csv", stringsAsFactors=F, header=F)
sec2 <- read.csv("C:\\exportdata\\sec2.csv", stringsAsFactors=F, header=F)

# The first column contains dates.  
# I use strptime to tell it what format these appear in.
sec1_dates <- strptime(sec1[,1], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
sec2_dates <- strptime(sec2[,1], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

# The second column contains the close prices for the securities.
# I use the zoo function to create zoo objects from that data.
# Input =  a vector of data and a vector of dates.
a <- zoo(sec1[,2], sec1_dates)
b <- zoo(sec2[,2], sec2_dates)

# create a discrete time-series with the exact time frame desired
# per tip from James
template <- zoo(NULL, seq(sec1_dates[1], tail(sec1_dates, 1), "min"))
template <- template[which(strftime(time(template),"%H:%M")>"08:30" & strftime(time(template),"%H:%M")<"15:00")]

# The merge function is then used to merge
# 1) each security to the template (uses the discrete date/time range)
# 2) remove the column of data from template (used only for dates)
# 3) each security to one another (this was the ultimate goal anyway.
a.zoo <- merge(a, template, all=TRUE)
a.zoo$template <- NULL
b.zoo <- merge(b, template, all=TRUE)
b.zoo$template <- NULL
t.zoo <- merge(a.zoo, b.zoo, all=TRUE)

# Fill all NA elements with the closest non NA value.
t <- na.locf(t.zoo)
```

Comment: -1 Please clarify problem by providing sample data.  Use `dput` to do that.  Show what you get and how it differs from what you want.  The "obviously it fails" is not obvious at all.  `merge.zoo` does not require matching indexes.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM 1**

`?zoo` has details on how to deal with duplicates, but this is presumably because you have duplicates in your dates created by `strptime`.

**PROBLEM 2**

You can subset times using `[`, `which` and `time` with `zoo` objects, see `?zoo`, eg:

```
t.zoo[which(strftime(time(t.zoo),"%H:%M")>"08:30" & strftime(time(t.zoo),"%H:%M")<"15:30")]
```

**PROBLEM 3**

Use `c` to combine: `t.zoo <- c(a,b)`

Comment: James, thank you so much for your help! I used your solution to problems 1 and 2, and I'm fairly certain that using c to combine in place of the final merge would improve the speed with which my code will process. Are there any additional modifications you would suggest? (note: I did update the code above)